# Installing the community release of PGI in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: software-installation

I want to install [PGI Community Edition Version 19.4](https://www.pgroup.com/products/community.htm) in my computer.

After downloading the files, I executed the `install` script in the main folder and that caused an installation wizard to start doing things.

However, a number of errors appeared during the installation (see the complete log [here](https://gist.github.com/Jsevillamol/20c143b4906f985945f080ca82a5de16)), and after it finished and exporting to PATH the variables indicated in the [installation guide](https://www.pgroup.com/resources/docs/19.4/x86/pgi-install-guide/index.htm) it wont let me compile programs with pgcc.

Concretely, calling pgcc causes a `permission denied` error.

How do I fix it?

Comment: may be you should add the `sudo` to the pgcc command!

Comment: The first error happens when you try to create `/opt/pgi/`. So I think you should rerun the install, this time as `sudo install`.

Comment: @Jos I was running it as sudo ./install, should I just try again?

Comment: Strange: all file handling shows `Permission error`, directories don't get created, etc., which is something I should expect when you try to `install` without `sudo`. But yes, try again.

Comment: @Jos I get the same outcome :/

Comment: Is there already a directory `/opt/pgi/`? If so, what are its permissions?

Comment: @Jos there is already a pgi folder (albeit AFAIK there was none the first time I tried the script). It has these permissions: `drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 may  9 17:27 pgi`